# Difference Between DataInputStream/DataOutputStream Class & InputStream/OutputStream Class

Tags: java, android, java-me, datainputstream

Whenever I use `HttpConnection` Class in `Java ME`, `Android` or in `BlackBerry`, I uses `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` class for reading & writing datas over remote server.  However there are other class like `InputStream`/`OutputStream` which can be use for same purpose. I saw Question regarding `InputStream`/`OutputStream` class with `HttpConnection`. So I would like to know from experts that what are the differences between these two ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` is an `InputStream`/`Outputstream`.  `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are the most generic IO streams you can use and they are the base class of all streams in Java.  You can read and write raw bytes only with them. `DataInputStream` writes formatted binary data. Instead of just simple unformatted bytes, you can read `Bytes`, `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, `Short`, UTF-8 strings, and any mixture of that data.  And the same can be said for `DataOutputStream` except that it writes these higher level data types.

A `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` has a reference to an `InputStream`/`OutputStream` which it reads the raw bytes and interprets those bytes as those previously mentioned data types.

Although reading strings from the `DataInputStream` isn't a good idea because it makes unchangeable assumptions about the character encoding of the underlying `InputStream`.  Instead, it's better to use a `Reader` which will properly apply character encodings to the underlying byte stream to read data.  That's why `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` is of limited use.  Typically it's better to trade textual data between processes because it's easiest to make a server and client agree on how to parse the data.  Trading binary has lots of bit twiddling that has to occur to make sure each process is talking the same language. It's easy if you have two Java processes using `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`, but if you ever want to add a new client that isn't Java you'll have a harder time reusing it. Not impossible, but just harder.

Answer (score 5):

**DataOutputStream** can only handle basic types.

It can only read/write **primtive types** and **Strings**.DataInput/OutputStream performs generally better because its much simpler.

**ObjectInput/OutputStream** can read/write any **object type** was well as **primitives**. It is less efficient but much easier to use if you want to send complex data.

With the ObjectOutputStream class, instances of a class that implements `Serializable` can be written to the output stream, and can be read back with ObjectInputStream.

I would assume that the **Object*Stream** is the **best choice** until you know that its **performance** is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

**DataOutputStream** makes sure the data is formatted in a platform independent way

**OutputStream** only if you transfer raw binary data.

**DataOutputStream**-This is the big benefit.

There is no significant performance difference between both.